# To remove common string from two string array in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, string

I have two string arrays (str and str1):

```
   string[] str = new string[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat" };
   string[] str1 = new string[] { "Mon", "Tues", "Wed" };
   string[] str2 = new string[10];
```

I want to create a new array which will contain the items that appears only in one of the arrays.
The output will be:

```
str2[]={"Sun","Thur","Fri","Sat"}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it produces the set difference of two sequences by using the default equality comparer to compare values.

```
 var str2= str.Except(str1);
```

NOTE: Don't forget to add `System.Linq` namespace like;

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: @user3140153, Did you included `System.Linq`. See Soner Gönül has provided working demo

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method with LINQ. Don't forget to add [`System.Linq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace. like;

> Produces the set difference of two sequences by using the default
>   equality comparer to compare values.

```
string[] str = new string[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat" };
string[] str1 = new string[] { "Mon", "Tues", "Wed" };

var str2 = str.Except(str1);

foreach (var i in str2)
{
   Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Output will be;

```
Sun
Thur
Fri
Sat
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/CA61s2)</kbd>.

Comment: @user3140153 You are quite welcome. If one of these answers solved your problem, please consider to accept one http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] str = new string[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat" };
string[] str1 = new string[] { "Mon", "Tues", "Wed" };

var str2 = str.Where(t => !str1.Contains(t)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `Where` with `Contains`

```
var str2 = str.Where(s => !(str1.Contains(s)).Select(s => s);
```